# How to use TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory with a AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I have found 'TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' from the Spring Boot project which can create a Tomcat embedded instance.
I already have a set of "traditional" Spring (Java based) configuration classes plus a 'AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer' implementation for setting up a root application context and the controller context

```
public class IntegrationTestDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{ServiceModuleConfiguration.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{WebModuleConfiguration.class };
}
}
```

Now I try to create a Tomcat instance with

```
TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory("/", 8080);
tomcatFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(???)
```

getEmbeddedServletContainer() expects a  ServletContextInitializer from Spring boot and now I'm stuck with bridging that to my configuration classes.

**Is Spring Boot's tomcat factory built for supporting this?** If so,any examples out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` really pairs with `EmbeddedWebApplicationContext` (not the `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` you get from `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`). If you want to build a WAR file then your best option given the simple nature of the initializer is to use `SpringApplicationServletInitializer` instead, e.g.

```
public class IntegrationTestDispatcherServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ServiceModuleConfiguration.class).child(WebModuleConfiguration.class);
    }

}
```

If you don't want a WAR file (as suggested in comments, and when I think about it more) just create a `SpringApplication`, which uses `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` if it thinks you are trying to build a webapp (or use the builder as in the code above).

Comment: I don't get the `SpringServletContainerInitializer`kicking in to initialize the web application. 
I'm using a `AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext` with a bean definition for a `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory`. The container itself starts, but I guess in order for the above `IntegrationTestDispatcherServletInitializer` the `SpringServletContainerInitializer`has to be run?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was confused about what you want to do. If you don't want to build a war file and deploy it then a `ServletContextInitializer` isn't going to help, and if you want the embedded container you probably don't want a war file. Why not just use `SpringApplication` or the builder directly?

Comment: Ok, will investigate towards this. My intention is to run a simple integration test from an embedded tomcat without the hassle of building a WAR and deploy it.

Comment: `SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(WebModuleConfiguration.class,ServiceModuleConfiguration.class);
builder.contextClass(AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.class);
builder.application().run();`

This is booting the context, however it doesn't look like this gives me a working DispatcherServlet setup. But now the question is if I had to register it manually like I would do it with `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer` I would need access to the application context with the controller beans? I don't see how one would get the from the builder/application?

Comment: Right, I see. To get a `DispatcherServlet` to own your context you need to create a `@Bean` of that type and put it in your application context. Shouldn't be a big deal? N.B. though, to preserve the application context hierarchy from your original app you will need to use `SpringApplicationBuilder` (or equivalent) like in the sample above. OTOH maybe your original app didn't need that hierarchy (most apps don't).

Comment: Really it is the hierarchy that is puzzling. Putting all configurations into a single context works. Obviously the `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` has to be in the `AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext`. 

Then putting
`builder.sources(ServiceModuleConfiguration.class,TomcatContainerFactoryConfiguration.class).child(WebModuleConfiguration.class, DispatcherServletConfiguration.class);` leads to the situation that the `DispatcherServlet`configured by the `DispatcherServletConfiguration` is not loaded anymore.

Comment: Right. The servlet should be in the child context (which is how it would be if you used `@EnableAutoConfiguration` instead if wiring it all yourself.

Comment: This already turns into a lengthy discussionn. No matter how I twist it, it only works when having a single context (instead of a hierarchy). 

Do you think it would make sense if I open a JIRA feature request restating my goal. I see your EmbeddedTomcat abstraction extremely helpful for testing. My goal is to start tomcat, provide the application contexts with the option of hooking in mocks (for example mocked services)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47399/discussion-between-dave-syer-and-martin-ahrer)

Answer (score 0):

With some more debugging and some more input from Dave the right approach is to explicitly get the child builder instance and invoke it's run() method. This will start the context properly.

```
    SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder();
    builder.sources(ServiceModuleConfiguration.class);
    childBuilder = builder.child(WebModuleConfiguration.class, WebConfiguration.class, TomcatContainerFactoryConfigur‌​ation.class);
    childBuilder.run();
```

`WebConfiguration` contains the `DispatcherServlet` bean.

```
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new DispatcherServlet((WebApplicationContext) applicationContext), "/*");
    }
```

`TomcatContainerFactoryConfigur‌​ation` contains the `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean

```
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory("", 8080);
    }
```